# If $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{|T'_n|}{|T_n|} = 1$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{|T_n \Delta T'_n|}{|T_n|} = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, group-theory

Let $\{T_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a Folner sequence and $\{T'_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be any sequences of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{|T'_n|}{|T_n|} = 1$. Then, $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{|T_n \Delta T'_n|}{|T_n|} = 0$, where $\Delta$ means the symmetric difference.

$\{T_n\}$ being a Folner sequence means that for any $v \in \mathbb{Z}^d$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{1}{|T_n|}|vT_n \Delta T_n| = 0$, where $vT_n = \{vt^{(n)} : t^{(n)} \in T_n\}$.

Using the fact that $A \Delta C = (A \Delta B) \Delta (B \Delta C)$, we can write, for any $v \in \mathbb{Z}^d$ and any $n \in \mathbb{N}$

\begin{equation*}
T'_n \Delta T_n = (T'_n \Delta vT_n) \Delta (vT_n \Delta T_n). 
\end{equation*}

Then,

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{|T_n \Delta T'_n|}{|T_n|} = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{|(T'_n \Delta vT_n) \Delta (vT_n \Delta T_n)|}{|T_n|} $$.

As $\{T_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Folner, we know that $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{1}{|T_n|}|vT_n \Delta T_n| = 0$, for any $v \in \mathbb{Z}^d$.

I guess I need to find a suitable $v$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{|T'_n \Delta vT_n|}{T_n} = 0$ and I guess the existence of this $v$ is guaranteed by the hypothesis that $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{|T'_n|}{|T_n|} = 1$, but I am not sure if this is right and how I can justify that.

Could someone help me?